# Computing $\int_0^{e-1}dx\int_0^{e-x-1}dy\int_e^{x+y+e}\frac{\ln(z-x-y)}{(x-e)(x+y-e)}dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\int_0^{e-1}dx\int_0^{e-x-1}dy\int_e^{x+y+e}\frac{\ln(z-x-y)}{(x-e)(x+y-e)}dz$$
> Source: G. N. Berman task 3521

**My attempt:**

$$\int_e^{x+y+e}\ln(z-x-y)dz=\int_e^{x+y+e}\int_1^{z-x-y}\frac1tdt$$

$$\begin{aligned}1&\le t\le z-(x+y)\\ e&\le z\le e+(x+y)\\\iff 1&\le t\le e\\ 
 t+(x+y)&\le z\le e+(x+y)\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}&\int_1^e\frac1t\int_0^{e-1}\frac1{x-e}\int_0^{e-x-1}\frac1{x+y-e}\int_{t+(x+y)}^{e+(x+y)}dzdydxdt\\&=\int_1^e\frac1t\int_0^{e-1}\frac1{x-e}\int_0^{e-x-1}\frac1{x+y-e}(e-t)dydxdt\\&=\int_1^e\frac{e-t}t\int_0^{e-1}-\frac1{x-e}\ln|x-e|dxdt\\&=\begin{bmatrix}s=\ln|x-e|\\ds=\frac1{x-e}\end{bmatrix}\\&=-\int_1^e\frac{e-t}t\frac{s^2}2\Big|_1^0\\&=\frac12\int_1^e(e/t-1)dt\\&=\frac12\left(e\ln(t)-t\right)\Big|_1^e\\&=\frac12\end{aligned}$$

The solution in the book is $2e-5.$ Can anybody see my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits are wrong. Just take the case $x+y=1$. In your original condition the minimum value for $z$ is $e$, while in your calculated limits that goes down to $2$. Just to show my point, I plot the original condition with vertical lines, and your final limits with horizontal lines. Look at the region between $z=2$ and $z=e$:[image]

A better method would be to perform the first integration by parts

Comment: I think I see what I did. Thanks! The area I was parametrizing isn't a triangle in the $zt$ plane, so the point $(1,e)$ is on the line $t=z-(x+y)$ iff $x+y=e-1\iff y=e-x-1$ and that is only one scenario.